# unbind click event added to classes

Tags: jquery

I have the following line to add a click event to items with the same class:

```
jQuery('.multi_image').click(function(){onMultiImageClicked(jQuery(this));});
```

I am using the following code to try and unbind the click event:

```
jQuery('.multi_image').unbind('click');
```

However, the unbind does not seem to have any effect.

Is it possible to remove a click event from a class of objects like this?

Answer (score 2):

`.unbind('click')` must work... but I recommend to use `on` and `off` functions:

Use `on` and `off` functions instead:

```
jQuery('.multi_image').on("click", function (){
   onMultiImageClicked(jQuery(this));
});
```

and

```
jQuery('.multi_image').off("click");
```

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

> The `off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`. See the discussion of delegated and directly bound events on that page for more information. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names. **When multiple filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must match for the event handler to be removed.**

Comment: thanks. Turned out to be a logical error. The code I originally posted works. However, I appreciate being turned-on to the 'on' and 'off' options.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss Yes, it should. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery docs

```
Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind().
```

Since you are not using bind(), that might be the reason for this behavior. Try to use on(), off() or use bind() to bind the click handler before using unbind().